# VBA: How to remember the value from the previous iteration and set it as the initial value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a little problem with my code in VBA. Please see on the code below.

```
Sub MonteCarlo()


M = Cells(13, 2)  'number of iterations (step)

SumaMC = 0
non_zero = 0
For i = 1 To M
    SumaMC = SumaMC + Cells(27, 12)
    Cells(14, 2) = Cells(14, 2) + 1 'update number of iterations
    non_zero = non_zero + Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("L3:L26"), "<>0")
Next i
Cells(28, 14) = non_zero
Cells(27, 13) = SumaMC / Cells(14, 2)
Cells(27, 12) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("L2:L26"))
End Sub
```

I want to count the non-zero values in each iteration and sum them up. The code is working fine, but if I run the loop again, the sum of the nonzero values counts again for the iteration step. For example:

First run of the macro:
100 iterations and 326 non zero values

Second  run of the macro:
200 iterations and 324 non zero values ( and here it should be 326+324).

How to correct it?

Comment: put `Cells(28, 14)` in place of `non_zero`

Comment: @ScottCraner Unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: did you do `Cells(28, 14) = 0`?  If so remove that line.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thank you!